# How to change format of date in function

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this Javascript snippet that retrieves a start date from combobox and compares it to an end date, it then works out how many months are in between the start and end date and outputs that value into another textfield, then in the end takes the end date and adds one day to it and sets that value as the expiry date, its a simple function however I cant figure out how to fix the format of the dates
Right now when a person enters the start and end date the format is in Y,m,d this needs to be changed to Y-m-d (with hyphens), however this affects the function itself and then it does not work, I can easily change the format in extjs but I need to make sure the function still works after

Here is the function

```
function monthDiff(startdate, enddate) {
    var months;
    months = (enddate.getFullYear() - startdate.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= startdate.getMonth();
    months += enddate.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
var m = monthDiff(
    Ext.getCmp('startdateTextField').getValue(),
    Ext.getCmp('enddateTextField').getValue()
);
Ext.getCmp('durationTextField').setValue(m);

Date.prototype.addDays = function(d) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + d);
    return this;
};
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    var dd = this.getDate().toString();
    return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]);
};

var end = Ext.getCmp('enddateTextField').getValue();
end.addDays(1);
var enddate = end.yyyymmdd();
var expirydate = enddate;
Ext.getCmp('expirydateTextField').setValue(expirydate);
```

Let me know if I should post the extjs form code

Comment: I think I solved it, it might still work properly after all, may have just been frantic

Comment: The second i need to handle a date in javascript, i add the moment.js library to my project (http://momentjs.com/). It's incredibly easy to handle dates with it.

Comment: that's good to know ;) will use it in the future

Comment: Ext has a date library to do all this stuff for you, don't roll your own: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.Date

Answer (score 0):

if you are using extJS, I strongly suggest you use the `Ext.Date` (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Date) class to manipulate, format and parse date.